# Lambda for S3 triggering only once

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, triggers, aws-lambda, boto3

I've created a lambda function that triggers whenever any type of object is created in S3 bucket. My problem is it's triggered only once. In cloudwatch, I can see it's triggering only once, that is whenever first time a file is uploaded. I'm using event type All object create create events. When I upload the file second time, it doesn't trigger lambda function.

I want to trigger lambda function every time a file is uploaded to S3.

My python code in lambda function:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket('my-s3-bucket-for-images')

count = 0

print("I am triggered!!!")
```

I'm not sure if this qualifies as trigger configuration: but this is all I could see

```
Bucket: s3/my-s3-bucket-for-images Event type: ObjectCreated
```

I'm kind of new to aws. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That can't be answered with the trigger configuration.

Comment: @JakubKania You mean _without_ the trigger...

Comment: @hjpotter92 Yeah, that.

Comment: I've updated there. Now is that sufficient?

Comment: @tiredandboreddev Can you show the screenshot of the trigger config on the page where you configure your lambda?

Comment: Hi All, thanks for your questions and attempts to help. I figured out what was wrong. After I wrote this "lambda_handler" function in lambda function, it started working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured out what was happening. I was writing lambda function without this -

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #to do code here
```

Once I did this it started triggering every time I uploaded.